# How to start Outlook from unmanaged VC++ Code?

Tags: visual-c++, com, mfc, outlook, ole

Long story:
I've managed quite a few tasks with the extended Mapi libary from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10881/MAPIEx-Extended-MAPI-Wrapper. The problem is, it does not send the actual messages if Outlook is not running, it stores the messages in the outbox though, and to send them with a libary function require a login with a profile which I'll not alwas have.

Short story:
I need to start an installed Outlook (did already check) with its default profault profile so that it can send the messages in it's outbox, if any.

There are very mice and slick solutions in C#, 2 to 6 lines of Code but unfortunately I have to stick to unmanaged VC++.

First try:
I've already done quite a few things with the WIN32 OLE Interface and Microsoft Word. This time I only want the program to start, if not already running.
So I tried

```
// Outlook Test
CoInitialize(NULL);
CLSID clsid;
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Outlook.Application", &clsid);

IDispatch *pOApp;
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    IUnknown *pUnk;
    hr = GetActiveObject(clsid, NULL, (IUnknown**)&pUnk);
    if(FAILED(hr)) 
    {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, 
                               IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pOApp);
        if(FAILED(hr)) pOApp=NULL;
    }
    else if(pUnk) 
    {
        hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pOApp);
        if(FAILED(hr)) pOApp=NULL;
    }
}
```

But something is still missing.

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: Can we do this without having to guess what might be going wrong please?

Comment: I know whats wrong with this approach. I need at least to call one OLEMethod but I do not know which one because it's nowhere documented. I asked this question here in the slight hope, that somone more experienced with the WIN32OLE interface cold give me some advice where to go.

Comment: OR you could make another suggestion how I could open Outlook. I really hat this interface.

Comment: Do you get any error code in the code? You may find the https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2575036 and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/220600 articles helpful.

Comment: @masche Hans only pointed out that you didn't say anything about the value of the return codes in your code. Which API is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using a raw Extended MAPI code in unmanaged C++ without even automating Outlook. Moreover, in case of using the Outlook object model you will get a security prompt which the Send method triggers. You can read about this in the [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52) article.

See [How To Create a Message With an Attachment and Send It Using MAPI/VC++](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200174) for the sample in C++ (Extended MAPI).

Answer (score 0):

Import the Outlook type library (#import) so you can work with Outlook specific interfaces (such as Application).

```
#import "libid:00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" rename_namespace("Outlook") raw_interfaces_only
```

Or you can use late binding and call `IDispatch::GetIdsOfNames` / `Invoke`. You can see the properties / methods / events and their dispids in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click, for example, Application button on the OutlookSpy ribbon in Outlook).